# Errors recieved from Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, browser

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51216/devtools/browser/d1d6c024-df0e-46b4-916d-b55d036d31fb
[17668:20128:0420/155329.463:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
[17668:20128:0420/155343.164:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(162)] [15:53:43.163] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1055 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

I am using Selenium to run automated browser tests from python scripts. I keep getting these errors. They do not seem to be affecting the test run, but does anyone know why I'm getting them?

Comment: how did u resolved it ? or the error is still there ?